# How to include in a main QLabel a subset of widgets (e.g. QListView and QLabels)

Tags: qt, qlabel, qlistview

In order to test a rotation of a `QImage` I created a quick application where I subclassed a `QLabel` as shown below. Basically the `QLabel` acts as `MainWindow` for me in this case.

Below is the lay-out I have:

[image: be]

Below is the lay-out I am trying to achieve:

[image: be2]

Below the code

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QLabel {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent = {});
   virtual ~MainWindow();
protected:
   Q_SLOT void setImageMsg(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&);
   Q_SIGNAL void newImageMsg(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&);
private:
   ros::Subscriber sub;
   ros::Subscriber sub_img_bw;
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent) {
   qRegisterMetaType<sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr>();
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
   connect(this, &MainWindow::newImageMsg, this, &MainWindow::setImageMsg);
#else
   connect(this, SIGNAL(newImageMsg(sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr)), SLOT(setImageMsg(sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr)));
#endif
   ros::init(argc,argv,"MainWindow");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   QComboBox *comboColorBckgd = new QComboBox(this);
   QStringList sequence_len = QStringList() << tr("Bckgd Color") << tr("Green") << tr("Blue") << tr("Black");
   comboColorBckgd->addItems(sequence_len);

   QComboBox *comboColorBeam = new QComboBox(this);
   QStringList sequence_len_beam = QStringList() << tr("Beam Color") << tr("R") << tr("G") << tr("B");
   comboColorBeam->addItems(sequence_len_beam);

   QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout(this);
   grid->setColumnMinimumWidth(0, 10);
   grid->addWidget(comboColorBckgd, 0, 0, Qt::AlignTop);
   grid->addWidget(comboColorBeam, 0, 1, Qt::AlignTop);
   comboColorBckgd->show();
   comboColorBeam->show();
 }
```

I am facing here the situation where I don't exactly understand why I can't divide the main `QLabel` in subsessions where :

one row has one `QLabel` and one `QListView` and
another row has 'QListView`and`QLabel`

As shown in the layout I am trying to achieve.

Of course I tries to insert the necessary components in the function

```
`MainWindow::MainWindow(int argc, char** argv, QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent) {

      // .. desired componentns here
}
```

Despite I am able to add all the components my final layout is extremely disordered and everything falls under the single `QLabel` despite I am sure I set the `QGridLayout` correctly.

Maybe do I have to subclass a `QGridLayout`? I am confused.

I am not sure how to move on and I would like to thank anyone in advance for shedding light on what is happening or at lest pointing to a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to see your images for the layout you have and are trying to achieve so I may not totally understand your problem but...

Why do you have to subclass `QLabel`? I imagine that is causing your problems - `QLabel` is not expecting to have a child hierarchy underneath it and so it is probably conflicting with `QLabel`.

Instead of this parent/child hierarchy:

```
- MainWindow : public QLabel
-- QGridLayout
--- QComboBox
--- QComboBox
```

Have you tried:

```
- MainWindow : public QWidget (or QMainWindow?)
-- QGridLayout
--- QLabel (top level)
--- QComboBox
--- QComboBox
```